# How to make a modular Makefile for a modular c project?

Tags: c, makefile, header-files, modularity

I have a C program that has this code:

```c
#if defined(MATRIX)
    #include "Matrix.h"
#elif defined(QTREE)
    #include "QTree.h"
#endif
```

and I want to create a Makefile that given a target passes de -D flag to GCC with the corresponding MACRO so that the correct header + source files are compiled.

Currently I have this Makefile:

```
# Makefile for compiling the battleship game

C=gcc
STANDARD=c99
HEADER_DIR=includes
ODIR=obj
CFLAGS=$(C) -c -std=$(STANDARD) -I$(HEADER_DIR)
SDIR=src

_OBJS = Battleship.o Game.o Cell.o Ship.o Bitmap.o IO.o Aux.o Matrix.o QTree.o Board.o
OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJS))

# Program name
PROG=battleship

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.c
    $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(PROG1): $(OBJS)
    $(C) -o $(PROG) -D MATRIX $(OBJS)

$(PROG2): $(OBJS)
    $(C) -o $(PROG) -D QTREE $(OBJS)

.PHONY: game_with_matrix

game_with_matrix: $(PROG1)

.PHONY: game_with_qtree

game_with_qtree: $(PROG2)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o $(PROG)
```

but it always outputs: `make: Nothing to be done for [target].`

I don't really know whats wrong :(

EDIT:

when I invoke make I am using either `make game_with_matrix` or `make game_with_qtree`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you invoke `make`.  Do you specify a target explicitly?

Comment: yes, `make game_with_matrix` or `make game_with_qtree`

Comment: Do you want the executable to be called `battleship` in both cases? Or do you want `battleship_matrix` and `battleship_qtree`?

Comment: Does your compiler not complain about `$(C) -o -D MATRIX ...`?  That specifies an output filename of `-D` with `MATRIX` being an 'extra' argument.

Comment: @Beta battleship in both cases

Comment: yes, that was an oversight, I fixed it! but that wasn't the problem @G.M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this:

```
C=gcc
CFLAGS=$(C) -c -std=$(STANDARD) -I$(HEADER_DIR)

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.c
    $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

"CFLAGS" is a bad name for that. I strongly advise this:

```
C=gcc
CFLAGS= -c -std=$(STANDARD) -I$(HEADER_DIR)

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.c
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Now you could add a [target-specific variable value](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
$(PROG1): CFLAGS += -DMATRIX

$(PROG1): $(OBJS)
    $(C) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS)

$(PROG2): CFLAGS += -DQTREE

$(PROG2): $(OBJS)
    $(C) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

But you haven't yet defined `PRG1` nor `PROG2`, and I see no need for them. Get rid of them and do this:

```
$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(C) -o $@ $^

game_with_matrix: CFLAGS += -DMATRIX
game_with_matrix: $(PROG)

game_with_qtree: CFLAGS += -DQTREE
game_with_qtree: $(PROG)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This way is much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Is this the actual makefile you're using?  Because you've not defined either the variable `PROG1` or the variable `PROG2`, so if your makefile looks like that that's clearly the problem.

However, even if you fix that this is dangerous.  You should not put both types of objects into the same subdirectory.  You'll have to remember to always do a `make clean` when switching between them because make has no way to know if the previous build used the `MATRIX` or `QTREE` settings and you'll be trying to link object files compiled with different settings.

You should create two different `OBJ` directories, one for each, and use them when building that program.